# FileField/ImageField error: "An unrecoverable error occurred. Form missing from server cache"

Tags: 6, caching, media, files

After creating about 20 nodes and uploading an image in each of them (using FileField/ImageField), I get this error when trying to create another node with an image: "An unrecoverable error occurred. Form missing from server cache". When this error shows up the image field disappears.

I've already tried:

- Replacing `if (isset($user->cache) && $user->cache > $cache->created)
  {` with `if (isset($user->cache) && $user->cache > $cache->expire) {`
  in includes/cache.inc;
- Setting minimum cache lifetime to none;
- Adding `max_allowed_packet = 16M` to the my.cnf file;
- Repairing "`cache_form`" table;

I'm not using neither memcache nor cacherouter. Thoughts?

Comment: I'm assuming you've already looked at this issue correct? http://drupal.org/node/500646. Can you repo this with a minimum number of modules installed?